# codeblocks doesn't work on windows 8 or 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-8.1, codeblocks

I really need your help. I just purchased a new laptop, it has windwos 8 operating system, and I am trying to practice my c++ code, but it gives me error and doesn't output. Please help...
Here is what I get when I run simple "Hello world" program.

```
||=== Build: Debug in codeblocks_testing (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsndfile|
ld.exe||cannot find -lglew|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you installed the "sndfile" and "glew" libraries?

Comment: how do you install these libraries? I am sorry, I am not good at codeblocks.